# exporting indesign character / paragraph styles to javascript

Tags: javascript, export, adobe-indesign

If I set up a document's paragraph / character styles, how can I export them to javascript so they can be recreated via javascript scripting?

Comment: Character styles (usually) have only a small set of properties, but paragraph styles have around 180. Do you need them all? What about a style based on another -- do you styles need to copy "parents" as well, or be stand-alone?

Comment: I don't need all the properties, and don't mind parent relationships but it's a bind having to write 15-20 lines or so of javascript for a paragraph style after having set it up in InDesign, so an InDesign-to-Javascript method would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

The number of unique properties in Character and Paragraph Styles is very high; in CS4, about 170 for paragraphs, about 80 for characters. This includes both the familiar ones (`name`, `tracking`) as well as the bizarre (`otfTitling`, `underlineGapOverprint`, `gradientStrokeLength`). Fortunately, one rarely needs an *exact* clone of a style (including *all* of its properties). Also, usually a Character Style only defines a few properties.

The easiest way to create a style out of nothing is to assume reasonable defaults for all values and only *set* the properties that deviate.

There are a few caveats, though. Some properties need new items to be created in other places -- such as the `fillColor` of a style. Should the script also recreate this color? What if it already exists, but with a different *value* or *color model*? (Should it use the existing one, overwrite it, or create a new color?) What if the color *value* exists -- but under another name? (Should it scan the existing list for a match?) The same goes for a 'parent' style; what if an entire tree of styles needs to be created? What about `dropCapStyle`, `nestedStyles`, `nestedGrepStyles`, and `nestedLineStyles`? Do these need their *character* styles re-created?

Another potential pitfall is the measurement unit in use. Some of the properties are 'absolute', such as `pointSize`; others depend on the horizontal (`leftIndent`) or vertical (`spaceBefore`) rule settings. (My script below saves the units in use *when the script is run*, and restores them when done.)

The following script writes out a new script that defines a list of properties that you can easily edit and append (bearing the above-mentioned caveats in mind). A full list of all Paragraph/Character Style properties can be found in the ESTK Help menu, or online at [ParagraphStyle](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_ParagraphStyle.html) and [CharacterStyle](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_CharacterStyle.html)*.

This is just a basic framework, and it can be easily adapted for other purposes. Note that it is hardcoded to use a certain style name; `Body Text` -- this can be replaced with

```
var parstyle = app.selection[0].appliedParagraphStyle;
```

if you want to click inside a styled paragraph to save its style. It can also be adjusted to create a character style, in which case you need to test if a property is *undefined*, that is, if it is not an override.

```
//DESCRIPTION: Create a script to create a par-style
// A Jongware Script 28-Sep-2014

var parstyle = app.activeDocument.paragraphStyles.item("Body Text");
var reference = app.activeDocument.paragraphStyles.item(0);

var properties = [
    "name",
    "appliedFont",
    "fontStyle",
    "pointSize",
    "leading",
    "hyphenation",
    "justification",
    "firstLineIndent",
    "leftIndent",
    "rightIndent",
    "spaceBefore",
    "spaceAfter"
];

r = [];
for (i=0; i<properties.length; i++)
{
    if (parstyle[properties[i]] != reference[properties[i]])
    {
        if (parstyle[properties[i]].hasOwnProperty('name'))
            r.push ([properties[i], '"'+parstyle[properties[i]].name+'"']);
        else
        {
            if (parstyle[properties[i]].constructor.name == 'String')
                r.push ([properties[i], '"'+parstyle[properties[i]]+'"']);
            else
                r.push ([properties[i], parstyle[properties[i]]]);
        }
    }
}

scriptFile = File(app.activeScript.path+'/create_'+parstyle.name+'.jsx');
if (scriptFile.open('w') == false)
{
    alert ("Unable to create new script!");
} else
{
    d = new Date();
    scriptFile.writeln ('//DESCRIPTION: create par style \"'+parstyle.name+'"');
    scriptFile.writeln ('// A Jongware Subscript '+d.getDate()+'-'+['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'][d.getMonth()]+'-'+d.getFullYear());
    scriptFile.writeln ();
    scriptFile.writeln ('with (app.activeDocument.viewPreferences)');
    scriptFile.writeln ('// save current measurement units');
    scriptFile.writeln ('{\tvar ph = horizontalMeasurementUnits;');
    scriptFile.writeln ('\tvar pv = verticalMeasurementUnits;');

    scriptFile.writeln ('// set measurement units:');
    scriptFile.writeln ('\thorizontalMeasurementUnits = '+app.activeDocument.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits+';');
    scriptFile.writeln ('\tverticalMeasurementUnits = '+app.activeDocument.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits+';');
    scriptFile.writeln ('};');

    scriptFile.writeln ('app.activeDocument.paragraphStyles.add({');
    for (i=0; i<r.length; i++)
    {
        scriptFile.writeln ('\t'+r[i][0]+': '+r[i][1]+',');
    }
    scriptFile.writeln ('});');

    scriptFile.writeln ('// restore original measurement units');
    scriptFile.writeln ('with (app.activeDocument.viewPreferences)');
    scriptFile.writeln ('{\thorizontalMeasurementUnits = ph;');
    scriptFile.writeln ('\tverticalMeasurementUnits = pv;');
    scriptFile.writeln ('};');

    scriptFile.close();
}
```

---

<sup>* On-line versions of my re-interpretation of Adobe's official help files, as supplied with their ESTK. Various downloadable versions can be found at http://www.jongware.com/idjshelp.html. Bandwidth at MIT courteously provided by Mr. John Hawkinson.</sup>